# Position elements in minipage so that they align vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, enumerate, minipage

I'm trying to align tikz figures with a group of enumerated items bundled together in minipages:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \item One circle
    \item Two circles
    \item Three circles
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \end {tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \item One rectangle
    \item Two rectangles
    \item Three rectangles
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end {tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \item One triangle
    \item Two triangles
    \item Three triangles
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- cycle;
    \end {tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
```

The result does not align: 
[image: Result of code]

How can the images be aligned (e.g. centered vertically?) with the items?

Comment: which document class do you use?

Comment: Changing all six instances of `[t]` to `[c]` (the default) gets the job done. Is there a reason for specifying `[t]`?

Comment: @Mico: oh, I feel stupid now. For some reason I thought there was no [c] option for minipage, and that these alignment options are mandatory... Now I see that in any case, [c] or [] gives my wanted result. Ooops. Thanks!

Comment: @pelegs - You're certainly not stupid! In all likelihood, you picked up an incorrect piece of information from somebody else in the past, and this posting served the useful purpose of debunking an incorrect belief...

Comment: @Mico: Yeah, you learn from mistakes such as this, that's true :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing all six instances of the `[t]` position specifiers to `[c]` seems to get the job done.

For the following example, I had to guess which font size should be used; if `12pt` is incorrect, please let us know what should be used instead. I changed the widths of the `minipage` environments to place the visual elements more closely together.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \item One circle
    \item Two circles
    \item Three circles
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) circle (0.925);
    \end {tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \item One rectangle
    \item Two rectangles
    \item Three rectangles
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.85,1.85);
    \end {tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \item One triangle
    \item Two triangles
    \item Three triangles
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) -- (0,1.85) -- (1.85,1.85) -- cycle;
    \end {tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeap, for some reason thought I must include either [t] or [b], which in retrospect does not make sense... Thanks!